# Unable to print complete API URL in karate response

Tags: karate

Question #1:

I am unable to print the complete API URL in karate response (base url + path + locale).

I used the below format

```
print APIURL 'url+path+localeparam'
```

Question #2:

I am trying to capture an API response and extract required fields from response and passing these fields to another API payload.

Please help me with these questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you need data from the response, use the `response` built-in object. For example:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/get'
* method get
* print response.url
```

Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#response